# Different size subnets on the same system

Tags: vlan, subnet

I am working at a school campus that has 3 programs on it and has a lot of politicking involved with network administration. I am in charge of the network administration for our program along with managing our domain.

Each program has its own VLAN keeping it separate from the other programs and then we have been given 4 subnets for our program:
192.168.216.0/24,
192.168.217.0/24,
192.168.218.0/24,
192.168.219.0/24

The other programs and equipment are all have 192.168.x.0/24 subnets

My question, since we do not need want separate subnets, if I convince the campus network administrator to switch us to 1 subnet 192.168.216.0/22, will this cause problems for the other subnets on the network? And, will a setup like this work?

In my mind this is the easiest way to deal with getting a larger subnet. I have tried to convince the campus to switch to a 10.0.0.0 range but seemed like an alternative since they will not listen.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "program", but how many host/network devices do you need to support in your "program"?

Comment: Basically we are 3 different schools sharing 1 campus and they call each one a "program." We have about 600 Devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a /22  has no impact on any of the subnets surrounding that range. But...

There are some valid concerns for not creating large subnets (although some advantages to do so as well), so do you have a genuine technical requirement do so and what are the reasons for the campus network administrator to oppose that?

In the real world IP re-numbering programmes are a big PITA, which you only do out of real necessity. Proposing to simply *switch to the 10.0.0.0 private range* is a quick way to loose your professional credibility.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly but here are some basics and assumptions:
If your subnet mask is /22 (255.255.252.0) then you can have up to 1022 hosts in this subnet.
If your subnet mask is /24 (255.255.255.0) then you can have up to 254 hosts in this subnet.

The IP configuration is on upper layer than the VLAN as it happens on layer 3 and VLAN on layer 2 from the OSI model. VLANs are what keeps your different programs in separate virtual networks (it's the same like if it was physical networks, but sharing same equipment so it's virtual).

It is possible that your campus network administrator has gave you explicitly these networks, since may be there are some routing rules between different programs networks which are configured for those networks.

In additional the different subnets are separating your network in different broadcast domains. So if you have too many hosts there might be a reason to separate them in different broadcast domains. Also there may be many other reasons for doing that.

I hope this information helps you.